# Problema com validação de campos com ajax

Tags: ajax, html5, formulário

pessoal fiz uma validação via `ajax` no meu formulário do [site](http://medicalseg.com.br/contato) que quando o usuário não preenche o campo e tenta submeter  o `form` ele pega os inputs e adiciona uma borda vermelha até ai ta certinho porem quando os campos estão preenchidos e ele envia o formulário as bordas não desaparecem queria que elas desaparecem quando o usuário preencher os campos ou quando enviar o form ele simplesmente deixe as boras sem essa marcação vermelha segue um print da tela de um dos meus form e o código que eu fiz:

é assim que fica quando envio sem preencher
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

depois que preencho e envio ele continua com as bordas e a mensagem que adicionei atras do modal vocês  vão conseguir ver que ao enviar ele contnua assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

JS:

```
//Contact Us
$(".send-form").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $('form').serializeArray();

    var cont = 0;
    $("#form .input-contact").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "")
        {
            $(".required-fields-contact").show();
            $(this).css({"border" : "1px solid #F00", "padding": "2px"});
            cont++;
        }
    });
    if(cont != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Ajax post data to server
    $('.loaderImage').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/contato',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#modal-success').modal('show');
            $('.loaderImage').hide();
            $('form').trigger("reset");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

OBS: Link do site está no começo da questão caso queiram testar

Comment: Antes uma pergunta dentro do ajax ele retorna uma mensagem dizendo que foi realizado com sucesso ou algo assim? tente assim se retornar success: function (data) {
            $('#modal-success').modal('show');
            $('.loaderImage').hide();
            $('form').trigger("reset"); if(data != ""){ $('#form .input-contact').css({"border" : "1px solid black", "padding": "2px"});
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por que não usar um script já pronto? Tão mais simples. Ele vai fazer toda a verificação de quando o campo está ou não de acordo com as regras. Indico o https://jqueryvalidation.org/

De todo modo, se quiser manter a solução atual, seu código deveria eliminar a marcação que você adicionou, mais ou menos assim:

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#modal-success').modal('show');
    $('.loaderImage').hide();
    $('form').trigger("reset");

    $(".required-fields-contact").hide();        
    $("#form .input-contact").each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr("style");
    });
},
```

Porém, eu recomendaria a você criar uma classe para sinalizar o erro e depois remove-la:

```
$("#form .input-contact").each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "")
    {
        $(".required-fields-contact").show();
        $(this).addClass("error");
        cont++;
    }
});
```

e:

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#modal-success').modal('show');
    $('.loaderImage').hide();
    $('form').trigger("reset");

    $(".required-fields-contact").hide();    
    $("#form .input-contact").each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("error");
    });
},
```